# Adding an OPC UA Server to .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, opc, scada, opc-ua

I have a C# application that communicates with a process instrument over ethernet. I want to add an OPC UA server to my application so that any SCADA system with a built in OPC client can connect and read measurement data taken by the instrument. Does any one know of any 3rd party dll's that I can use?

I'm not looking for something that is free or open source, but the license terms would need to allow for me to re-sell as part of my application.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The OPC Foundation announced their [“OPC UA Open Shared Source” Strategy](https://opcfoundation.org/news/press-releases/2134/) (04/14/2015).

The stack for .NET including lots of samples for DA, Historie... clients and servers can freely be downloaded here [OPCFoundation/UA-.NET](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET)  on GitHub.

Very nice but the problem is the license that comes with it. It basically can only be used by OPC members since everybody else needs to make their software that uses it open source under GPL 2.0.

I wish they would simply offer developer licenses with a one time fee..

A truly free library that can be used in commercial applications is [Open62541](https://github.com/open62541/open62541) (LGPL + static linking exception). But using it with .NET requires extra work since it's C-based...

Answer (score 3):

You need to buy OPC UA SDK to allow your C# application to use OPC UA .

Then you can try with OPC UA Client such as the one from Unified Automation : http://www.unified-automation.com/opc-ua-clients/ (Free for WIN32, Linux and Android !)

There is also some SCADA already supporting OPC UA like Genesis from Iconics : http://www.iconics.com/Home/Products/HMI-SCADA-Software-Solutions/GENESIS32.aspx (Free trial)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [www.opcfoundation.org](http://www.opcfoundation.org). They have links to vendors who make OPC client and server toolkits that you can use in your application. Most of them are royalty-free. Be aware that there aren't too many SCADA systems that support OPC UA yet; most of them only support OPC DA.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just doing a little more searching around and I did find that OPC DA is probably what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best collection of OPC client and server libraries that you can use:
http://www.opcconnect.com/dotnet.php